# How to set serialize data to ajax $.post method

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am trying `$.post()` method for first time, Have seen the documentation over [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), but unable to send any data to my php file.

Code on my js file:-

```
    submitHandler: function (form) {
    var data = $(form).serialize();
    $.post("test.php", function( data ){
        //console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

I know I am doing somthing wrong but can not figure it out. On my php file `var_dump($_REQUEST)` gives me null array.

Comment: `$.post("test.php", data, function( response ){
        //console.log(response);
    });
    return false;
}`

Comment: it worked :), thank you @Anant

Comment: Rajesh Dey welcome :):)

Comment: how to receive any value from the php file. if($updateUserResult){ $response['userId'] = $userId; } json_encode($response); , on recent code I have got empty on my console area @Anant. `$updateUserResult` is `boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can do it in many ways:-***

```
$.post("test.php", data, function( response ){  // you missed sending form data part here which i have added 
   console.log(response); 
});
```

**OR**

```
$.post( "test.php", $(form).serialize()).done(function( data ) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

**OR**

```
var data = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Note:- this is not only the end. Some more ways are there too

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the data as the second argument. The response is returned to the callback function `"done()"`

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
var data = $(form).serialize();
$.post( "test.php", data)
  .done(function( response ) {
     console.log(response);
  });
}
```